# checkbox doesn't check in dataTable

Tags: jsf, checkbox, primefaces, datatable, xhtml

So I have a small bug to fix, this part of code isn't written by me, so I don't really know why this happening.

So there is a `<p:dataTable>` in a `<p:tab>`

and first column is just a a `checkBox` to put a checkMark on particular row or to check all rows in a table.

[image]

So when I check first checkbox it checks every row, but it doesn't put a check mark on it's self..

Any ideas why is that?

This is the markup for this column:

```
<p:column style="width:16px;text-align:center" selectionMode="multiple" rendered="#{!serviceFolder.isAccess}"/>
```

using JSF , primefaces 5.1

Comment: Can you post the code where checkbox is used ?

Comment: I think I found a solution, it does check the checkBox, but the  checkMark is hidden, all I need is to change CSS and un-hide it. 

I dont know if it comes as default from Primefaces, or it's a bug from our code, but it will work for now. :)

Comment: Yes..correct, someone did some weird CSS modifications on that dataTable.. 

so, problem solved.